# click event on recyclerview item causing activity to freeze?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a recyclerview in an activity in android with various types of Item objects ( bound to Different views). when I click on a button on one of the recyclerview views, It is supposed to fire an event which in turn opens a new activity. This works the first time i tap it, but, when I try to enter the activity again This click event causes the activity to freeze? the only debug output im getting is this. No outofmemoryexception or  anything helpful like that.

```
[Mono] [0xb96777f0] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
[ViewRootImpl] changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
[ViewRootImpl] changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=false
[Mono] [0xba234a20] worker finishing
```

when I click on the "Button". Which is a is a relativelayout with a click listner attached. I add data to a bundle an call StartActivity(). below is my method to open this activity

```
public override void openActivity(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RelativeLayout btn = (RelativeLayout) sender;
        int pos = (int) btn.GetTag (Resource.Id.bottom_btn);
        TweetPicItem picitem = (TweetPicItem) newsitems[pos];
        var tweetactivity = new Intent(cont, typeof(TweetActivityImage));

        tweetactivity.PutExtra("content", picitem.BodyText);
        tweetactivity.PutExtra("name", picitem.TeamName);
        tweetactivity.PutExtra("image_url", picitem.TweetImage);
        tweetactivity.PutExtra("club", picitem.CreatedBy);
        tweetactivity.PutExtra ("tint", picitem.BackgroundColour);
        tweetactivity.PutExtra("isliked", picitem.ILikeThis);
        tweetactivity.PutExtra("tweetid", picitem.Id);

        if(picitem.Comments != null)
            tweetactivity.PutExtra("comments" ,  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(picitem.Comments));

       cont.StartActivity(tweetactivity, options.ToBundle());
    }
```

and in onBind I detach before reattaching the eventhandler each time

```
        vh.bottombtn.SetTag(Resource.Id.bottom_btn, position);
        vh.bottombtn.Click -= openActivity;
        vh.bottombtn.Click += openActivity;
```

So essentially the app freezes when i press a button. I cant really see where this issue is coming for due to lack of debug output? First i thought it was attaching eventhandlers in onbind but iam explicitly detaching evenhandler before attaching it each time? Ive also tried it on multiple devices and the issue persists. I know there is very little info to work with here, I am stumped myself, I thought the debug out put would warn me somehow but iam getting nothing back.  If anyone has any ideas id appreciate the help/ suggestions.

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the onClick handler, attach the debugger just before you click, and step through the code to see what's happening. Or, use the Traceview tool in Android monitor tool window. Turn it on before you press the button, press it, and turn it off when you are satisfied.(https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tips/traceview)

Comment: You can't typeCast   RelativeLayout btn = (RelativeLayout) sender;

Comment: oclickhandler executes fine. I have set a breakpoint on it and stepped through a number of times. Cant typecast a relativelayout? I seem to be able to get it back no problem?  no InvalidCastException? I also get the correct index back from the tag.

Comment: i appreciate the help though. thanks